# SQL: how do you perform aggregations when you can't use PARTITION the column?

Tags: sql, subquery, case, aggregate, window-functions

Below is an image of the table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPUGV.png

I have a table that tracks the users' visit of a mobile app. Each row represents the datetime when a user enters a page in the app. Min_btw_page shows the number of minute between each page visit. When Min_btw_page is >= 30 mins, the session is considered to be complete and the next page visit will be counted as a new session. What I am trying to find are:

1. The number of pages (namely rows) visited per session by each user (HashID);
2. The average minutes spent per session

I have used the lag() function to create "Min_btw_next_page". I have also created the column "row_no", attempting to give a sequence no. to each row by HashID by session, but I failed. The result should be like the column "Expected_row_no". However, even if I am able to achieve the right row number, I still do not know how to aggregate the rows by session as I would not be able to partition row number.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to distinguish 'sessions' for users. You define a new 'session' as one where the user hadn't done anything for  more than 30 minutes. As such, if someone does many actions, with 20 minutes or so between each action, it still counts as a single 'session'.

One approach (definitely not the only approach) would start with a minor change to what you have. Note also that here is only a partial answer - it's preparation for later analyses.

Note also that

- It's written in SQL Server - if you use something else, you'll need to review
- You get quicker and better solutions if you post the data in machine readable form, so we don't have to retype!
- I've avoided partitioning (except in the first LAG) - as requested. I assume you used a partition in the LAG to get your values though, so I used one there. It does, however, use the `SUM(column) OVER (ORDER BY ...)` to get a running total.

Here, what I'm doing is to create a column where all values in a 'session' get the same value e.g., the first six rows in your table get value 1, the next two rows get value 2, the next eight rows get value 3. From there, you can group by to find averages etc, and also doing other things like numbering become trivial.

Process involves

- Instead of finding the *next* VisitDateTime, find the *last* visit datetime. This is very important, because it enables us to determine (on the one row) if it's a new session or not via a simple DATEDIFF
- Each row that is a 'new session' is flagged with the value 1, otherwise 0.
- Then the sessions numbers are created by simply taking a running total of those flags

Data setup

```
CREATE TABLE #DeviceLoads (LogID int IDENTITY(1,1), HashID nvarchar(10), DeviceDatetime datetime);
INSERT INTO #DeviceLoads (HashID, DeviceDatetime) VALUES
('ID1', '20201013 15:26'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:26'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201014 14:59'),
('ID1', '20201014 14:59'),
('ID1', '20201014 16:17'),
('ID1', '20201014 16:46'),
('ID1', '20201014 17:15'),
('ID1', '20201014 17:46');
```

Here is the one command (feel free to split it up though).

- The CTE `DL_Source` uses the LAG function (similar to what you have, I believe, to create your original table) to determine the last activity time
- The CTE `DL_Session_Source` gets the data from above, and flags the new sessions with value 1
- The final SELECT creates the running total from `DL_Session_Source`

```
WITH DL_source AS   -- This is probably similar to what you have already
    (SELECT  LogID, HashID, DeviceDatetime, LAG(DeviceDatetime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY HashId ORDER BY DeviceDatetime, LogID) AS Last_DeviceDateTime
       FROM #DeviceLoads),
DL_Session_Source AS
    (SELECT  LogID, HashID, DeviceDatetime, Last_DeviceDateTime, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, Last_DeviceDateTime, DeviceDatetime) <= 30 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS New_Session_flag
       FROM DL_source)
SELECT  *, SUM(New_Session_flag) OVER (ORDER BY HashID, DeviceDatetime, LogID) AS Session_Num
  FROM  DL_Session_Source;
```

And here are the results (with seconds truncated for brevity). Note the column on the end (Session_Num) which indicates which rows are in which session.

```
LogID  HashID  DeviceDatetime    Last_DeviceDateTime   New_Session_flag    Session_Num
1      ID1     2020-10-13 15:26  NULL                  1                   1
2      ID1     2020-10-13 15:26  2020-10-13 15:26      0                   1
3      ID1     2020-10-13 15:28  2020-10-13 15:26      0                   1
4      ID1     2020-10-13 15:28  2020-10-13 15:28      0                   1
5      ID1     2020-10-13 15:28  2020-10-13 15:28      0                   1
6      ID1     2020-10-14 14:59  2020-10-13 15:28      1                   2
7      ID1     2020-10-14 14:59  2020-10-14 14:59      0                   2
8      ID1     2020-10-14 16:17  2020-10-14 14:59      1                   3
9      ID1     2020-10-14 16:46  2020-10-14 16:17      0                   3
10     ID1     2020-10-14 17:15  2020-10-14 16:46      0                   3
11     ID1     2020-10-14 17:46  2020-10-14 17:15      1                   4
```

From here, feel free to save to a temporary table or so for further processing e.g.,

```
SELECT Session_Num, 
       HashID, 
       COUNT(*) AS Num_Actions, 
       MIN(DeviceDateTime) AS First_Action,  
       MAX(DeviceDateTime) AS Last_Action
FROM #YourTempTable
GROUP BY Session_Num, HashID;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=297e0aaa406f25d420690a091bc5fc34) with some added 'interweaved' data (e.g., out of order and overlapping for HashID ID2) to help ensure it works as required.

Comment: Hi @seanb! Thank you for your prompt! My apology for not posting the data in machine readable form. Your solution is super clear and helpful. I can't believe I have spent the entire day trying to figure this out and you solved it so easily.

Comment: You'd already done the hard work with the LAG, I just turned it around a bit to allow the calculations on one row. One thing though - after writing this, I saw (in another question) an answer written by @GMB about [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491255/partial-sum-between-different-records-using-sql-2008/64491291#64491291) and saw similar processing - I think this it also applies here. If you research 'gaps and islands' you may find the same overall approach but better/more efficient code (when I wrote the above, I hadn't tried to understand that problem/solution)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to accomplish the requirements would be to use a combination of `DATEDIFF`, `FIRST_VALUE`, and integer math to divide the minute differences by 30 minutes.  This creates distinct 30 minute session groupings within HashID window partitions.  Only one CTE is needed.

Data (similar to seanb)

```
drop table if exists #DeviceLoads;
go
create table #DeviceLoads (
  LogID                 int identity(1,1),
  HashID                nvarchar(10), 
  DeviceDatetime        datetime);

insert into #DeviceLoads (HashID, DeviceDatetime) values
('ID1', '20201013 15:26'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:26'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201013 15:28'),
('ID1', '20201014 14:59'),
('ID1', '20201014 14:59'),
('ID1', '20201014 16:17'),
('ID1', '20201014 16:46'),
('ID1', '20201014 17:15'),
('ID1', '20201014 17:46'),
('ID2', '20201014 14:59'),
('ID2', '20201014 16:17'),
('ID2', '20201014 16:27'),
('ID2', '20201014 16:37'),
('ID2', '20201014 16:46'),
('ID3', '20201014 17:15'),
('ID3', '20201014 17:46');
```

Query

```
with session_cte as (
    select *,  datediff(minute, first_value(DeviceDatetime) over 
                       (partition by HashID order by DeviceDatetime), 
                        DeviceDatetime)/30 Session_Num
    from #DeviceLoads)
select Session_Num, 
       HashID, 
       count(*) AS Num_Actions, 
       min(DeviceDateTime) AS First_Action,  
       max(DeviceDateTime) AS Last_Action
from session_cte
group by Session_Num, HashID;
```

Query to get the average session per HashID in minutes

```
with
session_cte as (
    select *,  datediff(minute, first_value(DeviceDatetime) over 
                       (partition by HashID order by DeviceDatetime), 
                        DeviceDatetime)/30 Session_Num
    from #DeviceLoads),
hash_cte as (
    select Session_Num, 
           HashID, 
           count(*) AS Num_Actions, 
           min(DeviceDateTime) AS First_Action,  
           max(DeviceDateTime) AS Last_Action
    from session_cte
    group by Session_Num, HashID)
select HashID, avg(datediff(minute, First_Action, Last_Action)*1.0) avg_session_min
from hash_cte
group by HashID;
```

Output

```
HashID  avg_session_min
ID1     0.333333
ID2     6.333333
ID3     0.000000
```